# VCPKG_ROOT not defined for CMake

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, cmake

I am trying to set up vcpkg with a CMake project. Since I intend to have multiple people with different platforms working on this project, I wanted to use an Environment Variable to set CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE instead of a command line argument as recommended here for cmake: https://vcpkg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/integration/

However, It appears that CMake is unable to find the VCPKG_ROOT environment variable. I made a small example separate from my project to see if the problem still exists and it does. Here is my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

#vcpkg init
if(DEFINED ENV{VCPKG_ROOT} AND NOT DEFINED CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE)

   MESSAGE("vcpkg root found")

  set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "$ENV{VCPKG_ROOT}/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
      CACHE STRING "")
else() 
  MESSAGE("vcpkg not found")
endif()

project ("CmakeVcpkgTestF")

add_executable (CmakeVcpkgTestF "CmakeVcpkgTestF.cpp" "CmakeVcpkgTestF.h")
```

And here is the associated output when buliding, note that "vcpkg not found is output" instead of "vcpkg root found"

```
1> CMake generation started for default configuration: 'x64-Debug (default)'.
1> Command line: "cmd.exe" /c "%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\chcp.com 65001 >NUL && "C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"  -G "Ninja"  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING="Debug" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="F:\VisualStudio2019\CmakeVcpkgTestF\out\install\x64-Debug (default)" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29333/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29333/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe"  -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\Ninja\ninja.exe" "F:\VisualStudio2019\CmakeVcpkgTestF" 2>&1"
1> Working directory: F:\VisualStudio2019\CmakeVcpkgTestF\out\build\x64-Debug (default)
1> [CMake] vcpkg not found
1> [CMake] -- Configuring done
1> [CMake] -- Generating done
1> [CMake] -- Build files have been written to: F:/VisualStudio2019/CmakeVcpkgTestF/out/build/x64-Debug (default)
1> Extracted CMake variables.
1> Extracted source files and headers.
1> Extracted code model.
1> Extracted includes paths.
1> CMake generation finished.
```

So far all I have done install vcpkg (running the required bootstrap as well), is there something else I need to do to get this to work? Also it is worth noting that vcpkg is installed at the root of my drive(specifically F:/vcpkg/vcpkg), not at root of the code, but I don't imagine that is causing the problem.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your output, this is the *second* time your code has run. Your `if` condition asks whether `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` is defined at all, but it *is*! You defined it as a cache variable, which was then loaded into the global scope on the second run.

You probably want a test more like this:

```
set(vcpkg "$ENV{VCPKG_ROOT}/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake")
if(NOT CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE AND EXISTS "${vcpkg}")
  set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "${vcpkg}"
      CACHE FILEPATH "CMake toolchain file")
  message(STATUS "vcpkg toolchain found: ${CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE}")
endif()
```